# How to color even/odd lines in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I want to set different background colors for even and odd lines in emacs, like it is often done in tables:

```
df vsdfv    <--gray
sdf ve f    <--white
d vdvew     <--gray
w34rv wfv   <--white
...and so on<--gray
```

Is there a ripe script for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [stripes mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/StripesMode).